# Display SQL data row change using Signal R

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I'm new to Signal R, My situation is below

- User inserts new record into table database
- There is a new notification displaying on web form

However the old notification is kept, the latest notification will be changed by other background color(Facebook or gmail) is an example.

Tech used:  Asp.net 4.5 Web form and SQL server 2012.

Thanks

Comment: That's a situation, but what's your problem?

Comment: mason, just only I need a demonstration of SQL notification in web page

Comment: What have you tried? When you insert the data, you can get an instance of the hub context and call your client side code from there.

Comment: I mean user insert a new record to database from other source such as webform, winform, phone. but how to display the change on web page?

Comment: This link will help you. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Broadcast-Real-time-SQL-69dd9fcc

Comment: Thank you so much Kiran Varsani, so can you send easier example, that's only data row changes and web changes without refeshing page

Comment: @DũngNguyễnVăn Just about any SignalR tutorial will tell you how to update parts of the DOM based on data received via SignalR.